# What's the name of this guitar technique?

Tags: guitar, technique

what the name of this vastly used technique in guitar rhythm sections (specially done with flamenco or classic guitars) and has a chick chick sound? I know how it is played but I don't know the name. May someone help me? Sorry if I have not asked this question in a right place!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dRRfQB7Xrfd0t4OXZDSFkyTFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

That is called dead notes or muted notes in acoustic finger style and classical. I am not sure what exactly is is called in flamenco.

Comment: Yeah, although not the same, and as you surely know, we also have kinda similar technique in electric guitar to do some funky rhythms with, but it's mostly related to the left hand unlike here which is related to the right hand. There, we can call that something like a funky rhythm. But here, I just wanted to know if this has a defined name or not that seems it isn't so. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know which of the sounds you're talking about, it's either 1) just the clicking of the player's nails against the strings being picked up by the mike, or 2) the [rasgueado technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado), basically hitting stings 4->1 with 3 or 4 fingers in any number of strokes.

Comment: Here's a shot of the waveform I uploaded, and in this example, the technique I'm talking about first appears somewhere about 1.10 secs:
http://i.imgur.com/3rHfLge.png
And here, I've copied that part in the picture above, into another mp3 file, here it is:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1dRRfQB7XrfanJGYl9OeEVyZms

So, it seems the first one, clipping nails on strings I mean, as xerotolerant also said above, has no standard or defined name in Guitar Techniques...